# does not show original product image in magento its show default image

Tags: php, magento

I have enter product in magento with image it successfully added, but in frontend its show default image on product, its dont show original image i have set base small default to my image. its does not show. why i dont know.

**i have try to debug using base image path but its show placeholder image.**

[image: listing page in front]

[image: admin page]

[image: view page in front]

Comment: Try flushing cache. Also Product Image Cache

Comment: i have try lots of time to flush cache

Comment: Also make sure, that the defaults for base, small and thumnail are set correctly for the store view

Comment: Yup check for your particular store view and re-upload again.

Comment: Lots of Thanks to @fab  i have store problem.  i have solved ..

Comment: Happy that your problem is resolved. But thanks only to a single person?